# Python 3.4 64-bit kernel32.GetModuleHandleW returns 32 bit address

Tags: ctypes, python-3.4

This python code is part of a debugger class from Greyhat Python; however, I'm not using the same environment as the author was, which was python 2.5.

For some reason the call to GetModuleHandleW is returning a value of 0x1AC60000.

The actual loaded address of msvcrt.dll is at 0x7FFB1AC60000.  I've checked this by directly using msvcrt = cdll.msvcrt and hmod = c_void_p(msvcrt._handle)

Can anyone explain why this is happening and how to fix the issue?

```
printf_address = debugger.func_resolve("msvcrt.dll", "printf")

def func_resolve(self, dll, function):
    error = None
    handle = kernel32.GetModuleHandleW(dll)
    address = kernel32.GetProcAddress(handle, function.encode("ascii"))

    if(address == 0):
        error = kernel32.GetLastError()
        print("Error: {}: {}".format(error, FormatError(error)))
    kernel32.CloseHandle(handle)
    return address
```

Comment: It seems that this "Greyhat Python" is filled with lazy ABI assumptions. You'll have to declare each function prototype via the `restype` and `argtypes` attributes as explained in the tutorial and reference. That said, this function can be implemented using just ctypes: `func_resolve = lambda dll, function: ctypes.c_void_p.from_buffer(ctypes.cdll[dll][function]).value`.

Comment: Normally I discourage using `ctypes.cdll` instead of `ctypes.CDLL`, at least within a module, but in this case the `cdll` cache avoids incrementing the DLL reference count.

Comment: BTW, this code should not be calling `CloseHandle` on a module handle. This will set the thread's `LastErrorValue` to `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`, or if a debugger is attached an exception will be raised for `STATUS_INVALID_HANDLE`. A module 'handle' is just the base address of the module; it is not a handle for a kernel object. What you can do is call `FreeLibrary` if the handle was obtained from `LoadLibrary`. But since `GetModuleHandle` does not increase the DLL's reference count, it should not be paired with `FreeLibrary`.

Comment: thanks for the clarifications, it works now after changing restypes and argtypes and getting rid of closehandle

Comment: Can you post your fixed code please? I am struggling with kind of the same matter right now and i always get that the module can't be found. I am basically trying to find the base address of an executable. Thanks a lot